# Using GDB for debugging netlink communication

Tags: linux, timeout, gdb, netlink

I have a multi-threaded application that communicates with a kernel module using netlink sockets. One of the threads in user mode application works as a server and kernel module works as a client. Roughly the kernel code is as follows:

```
timeout = 3500;
netlink_unicast();
wait:
__set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
timeout = schedule_timeout(timeout);
__set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
if (!timeout)
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "No response received\n");
    return -1;
}
if (message_status != UPDATED)
{
   printk(KERN_ERR "Somebody woke us up before we got a reply. Time left %d\n", timeout);
   __set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
   goto wait;
}
```

The **message_status** variable is updated in the netlink callback when the user mode application replies to this message. So basically the idea is to send a message and then wait at max timeout jiffies for the reply.

Now, using gdb, if I add a break point in any function that is called by netlink server thread in user mode, the break point is never hit and the kernel log is flooded with messages like

> Somebody woke us up before we got a reply. Time left 3499
>
> Somebody woke us up before we got a reply. Time left 3499
>
> Somebody woke us up before we got a reply. Time left 3499
>
> Somebody woke us up before we got a reply. Time left 3499
>
> ..
>
> ..
>
> Somebody woke us up before we got a reply. Time left 3498

Until I finally get

> No response received

What is causing the kernel thread to wake up from the timeout and how should I debug the user mode code?

PS: I am using 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 on RHEL 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Use gdb.  In gdb, you can use "info threads" to see the list of threads.  you can jump to a specific thread with the command "thread " where n is the desired thread.  You can set specific threads to break using "break  :  thread ".  See this section of the manual to control behavior of the program relative to thread stopping. ie. you can specify that all threads stop while you work on just one thread.  https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Thread-Stops.html#Thread-Stops